# java program that will display a menu for choices to perform

Tags: java, methods

Can anybody help fix this problem? I'm making a java program that will show a set of choices that will run the chosen program by the user using java methods. How can I initialize the variable? I've put a comment where the error is. Here is the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
performProgram();   
chooseNumber();
}


public static void performProgram(){
int number;
Scanner pj= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select a number that indicates what the program will perform");
    chooseOption();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
    number=pj.nextInt();
}


public static void chooseOption(){
    System.out.println("1. Display the factors of a number");
    System.out.println("2. Display whether a number is odd or even");
    System.out.println("3. Display whether a number is a perfect number or not");
    System.out.println("4. Display the elements of an array in ascending order");
    System.out.println("5. Display the sum of odd elements in the array");
}


public static void chooseNumber(){
int number;
//Error: variable might have not been initialized
    if(number == 1)
        getFactors();
    if(number == 2)
        displayOddEven();   
}

public static void getFactors(){
Scanner rz= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number=rz.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The factors of" + number + " are: ");
        for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
        if (number % i == 0){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        }   
}


public static void displayOddEven(){
Scanner gd= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number=gd.nextInt();
        if(number % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(number + "is an even number.");
        else
            System.out.print(number + "is an odd number.");
}
```

}

Comment: Please note that Java _is not_ JavaScript.

Comment: Return number from `performProgram()` and pass it into `chooseNumber()`.

Comment: If I change it to 0, it will not proceed to the following program.

Comment: My bad. thank you for correcting.

Comment: How would I write that?

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 0):

From the first method you are getting the number value, return that value and pass that as a parameter to the second method.
In your implementation now, the second method does not know what value the user has entered.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you create a local variable you have to initialize them, i.e give them a value. Local variables don't have a default value. This is why you are seeing that error in chooseNumber method.

To make your code work this is one of the way you can write your program:

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {
int number = performProgram();   
chooseNumber(number);
}


public static int performProgram(){
int number;
Scanner pj= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select a number that indicates what the program will perform");
    chooseOption();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
    number=pj.nextInt();
    return number
}


public static void chooseOption(){
    System.out.println("1. Display the factors of a number");
    System.out.println("2. Display whether a number is odd or even");
    System.out.println("3. Display whether a number is a perfect number or not");
    System.out.println("4. Display the elements of an array in ascending order");
    System.out.println("5. Display the sum of odd elements in the array");
}


public static void chooseNumber(int number){

//Error: variable might have not been initialized
    if(number == 1)
        getFactors();
    if(number == 2)
        displayOddEven();   
}

public static void getFactors(){
Scanner rz= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number=rz.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The factors of" + number + " are: ");
        for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
        if (number % i == 0){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        }   
}


public static void displayOddEven(){
Scanner gd= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number=gd.nextInt();
        if(number % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(number + "is an even number.");
        else
            System.out.print(number + "is an odd number.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!